# Reactor Netty HTTPS Proxy Support

Tags: java, reactor-netty

I'm using `reactor-netty:1.0.1` via `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:jar:2.4.0` and have a requirement to use a HTTP forward proxy with TLS.  I'm not seeing documentation that reactor netty supports this, but rather it only supports a HTTP proxy without TLS.  I'm referencing: https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/reference/index.html#_proxy_support, I'm wondering if I'm missing something?

```java
TcpClient tcpClient = TcpClient
    .create()
    .proxy(proxy -> 
        proxy.type(ProxyProvider.Proxy.HTTP)
            .address(new InetSocketAddress("proxy.domain.com", 443))
            .username(proxyUserId)
            .password(password -> proxyPassword)
   );
```

Exception received

```
io.netty.handler.proxy.ProxyConnectException: http, basic, proxy.domain.com/proxy.ip.address:443, 
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```